# math 30-1: pre-calculus. test

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Given: $\log_3 (x-y) = 2\ $ 
and $\ \log_3 (x+2y) = 4$
 find $x + y$.

I have already tried $3^4 = x+2y$ and $3^2 = x-y$.

I am stuck after that.

I am not sure how to approach this question or do it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations in your two unknowns X and Y. Find X and find Y and add them.

Comment: thanks. I didn't see it before, but I did after you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$3^2=x-y$$ and $$3^4=x+2y$$ by subtracting  we get $$3^4-3^2=3y$$ or $$3^3-3=y$$ multiplying the first equation by $2$ and adding both we get $$3x=3^2\cdot 2+3^4$$ thus $$x=6+3^2$$ therefore
$$x+y=6+3^3+3^3-3=57$$

Comment: thanks your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

$(3^2+3^4) + 3^4 = (2x + y) + (x + 2y) = 3(x+y)$

$x+y = 3+2 \times 3^3 = 57$